# excel function, get and compare different sheet cells values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Question about excel function, which one to use and how. If I have four columns (family_id; father_name; mother_name; child_id) in sheet1, and sheet2 I have two columns(child_name; child_id). 
For example:

```
sheet1: family_id/father_name/mother_name/child_id 
(111 father1 mother1 01; 
222 father2 mother2 02;
333 father2 mother2 03)

sheet2: child_name/child_id
(child1 01;
child2 01;
child3 01;
child4 02;
child5 03;
child6 03)
```

How to get name_id value from sheet1 to sheet2? The function should compare the cell values I think? The result in sheet2 should be like this:

```
child1 01 111;
child2 01 111;
child3 01 111;
child4 02 222;
child5 03 333;
child6 03 333;
```

I think, it should be something like this: if sheet1 child_id value = sheet2 child_id value, then get family_id value from sheet1 where child_id value = family_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in Sheet 2 cell C1 and pull it down.

`=index(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!D:D,0))`

Make sure both the lookup and the reference cells are the same data type (text, number) or this will throw an error.